# Maven or Jenkins to remove couchbase bucket documents

Tags: maven, jenkins, couchbase

I´m using couchbase, and I need to clean my bucket every time my Jenkins job run. I´ve been thinking in create a Java app to clean it before start, but I was wondering if is there any Jenkins or Maven plugin that maybe I can use in order to achieve what I want to. So far I could not found anything like that on google.
Any suggestion?.

Regards

Comment: could you provide more details as to why you need the job to empty the bucket instead of recreate it?

Comment: Because my bucket has several views which I just want to clean one

Comment: ah so you don't actually want to empty the bucket, but rather remove a view? or would the behavior I proposed in the `couchbase-maven-plugin` flush PR (see answers below) work? flush doesn't remove the views

Answer (score 2):

there's a notion of a "flush" in couchbase. it must be enabled on the bucket, and what it does is empty the bucket and remove data on disk.

you can use the REST api to trigger a flush (see the [REST flush doc](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/REST/rest-bucket-flush.html), note that in the examples there, the second `default` is the target bucket)

Comment: maybe I could see if a quick pull request to add support for that in the `couchbase-maven-plugin` suggested by [Verhagen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33343654/1113486) is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look into [couchbase-maven-plugin](http://www.stuartgunter.org/couchbase-maven-plugin/) ?

Comment: Yes I did, but as far as I see, only remove buckets. What we need is remove just the documents. Thanks